# Having issues editing an existing DB entry with Sails and Waterline

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

I'm using SailsJS as an API with Waterline connected to a MongoDB. I'm trying to put together an endpoint to edit existing DB entries but can't seem to get it to work and I'm hitting a wall as to why.

My route:

```
'post /edit/safety/:id': {
controller: 'SafetyController',
action: 'editSafety'
},
```

My controller function:

```
editSafety: function editSafety(req, res) {
 var id = req.params.id;
 Safety.findOneById(id).then((err, safety) => {
  if (err) {
    res.send(500, err);
    return;
  }
  if (!safety) {
    res.send(404, err);
    return;
  }
  safety.title = req.body.title;
  safety.description = req.body.description;
  safety.status = req.body.status;
  safety.save((err, updatedSafety) => {
    if (err) {
      re.send(500, err);
      return;
    }
    res.send(200, updatedSafety);
  });
 });
},
```

Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the main issue was transposing the response and err objects. It was successfully completing the query, but loading it into the err object which gets caught and a 500 error is thrown. So I changed that and simplified in a few other places.

```
editSafety: function editSafety(req, res) {
 var id = req.params.id;
 Safety.findOne(id).then((response, err) => {
  var safety = response;
  if (err) {
    res.send(500, err);
    return;
  }
  if (!response) {
    res.send(404, err);
    return;
  }
  safety.title = req.body.title;
  safety.description = req.body.description;
  safety.status = req.body.status;
  Safety.update({
      id: id
    }, safety)
    .then((result) => {
      res.json(200, 'Ok!');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      sails.log.error('SafetyController.editSafety', err);
    })
 });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize the `Safety.findOneById` method - is this something you have custom built? If not, then it is likely your problem.

Try swapping it for either:

```
Safety.findOne(id)
```

or

```
Safety.findOne({id: id})
```

Note that the returned object will be a model instance if the record exists, and `undefined` otherwise. If you decide to go with `Safety.find` instead then the returned value will be an array containing all models matching the query.

Comment: It wasn't custom built and I don't recall where I found it, but it was doing the job. I have however gone no a normal find method just to simplify things.